# Как ввести символ видимого пробела в Latex?

Tags: latex

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ввести данный символ в Latex?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50804/79376

Comment: Не понимаю, почему по приведенной ссылке приведены какие-то заумные команды. Неужели англоязычные пользователи ТеХ знают его хуже меня? Я прочитал [банального Львовского](https://www.mccme.ru/free-books/llang/newllang.pdf) и такими пустяками не напрягал людей. А чем вас команды `\quad`, `\qquad` не устраивают? А еще есть команда `\hspace{}`. И все эти команды работают в том числе и вне формул.

Comment: [прочтите, пожалуйста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). и вообще есть хороший принцип «делай как я». ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с [примерами **ответов**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa).

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, простите за тупость, что вы хотели этим сказать? Что я грубо ответил?

Comment: @Grek79, да. Такое сообщение с выпадами против спрашивающего может быть не очень приятно читать.

Comment: Я просто привык для получения знаний прикладывать усилия и сидел на сайте, где сообщения без попыток решения помещают в карантин, а с любителями халявы разговаривают в таком же духе. И считаю это все правильным.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/353130)

Comment: На каком бы сайте вы ни сидели, и как бы там ни разговаривали, сейчас вы пишете ответ на сайте Stackoverflow, у которого есть свои задачи (не флейм разводить, а делиться знаниями) и свои правила (разговаривать друг с другом уважительно). Если вы согласны с этими правилами, соблюдайте их, а если не согласны, то не пишите здесь ответов.

Comment: Нормальный ответ, чего многие агрятся? | По поводу англоязычных пользователей: их _очень_ много. Неудивительно, что среди такой толпы много начинающих, но репу они набрать хотят, вот и публикуют плохие ответы (хороших не знают).

Comment: Глянул по ссылке. Мда, там вовсе не начианющие, судя по репе... Однако они могут быть новичками в TeХ.

Comment: Так я, вроде, и помог. А что грубовато, так это будет стимулировать лишний раз в книгу заглянуть, а не искать халявы, засоряя форум.

Comment: @Grek79 простите, но как команда по заданию ширины поможет добавить нужный символ?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду команду \hspace?

Comment: Ой, извините, пожалуйста, я не понял вопроса. Попробую найти.

Comment: Я фигею. Просмотрел [вот это](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (кстати, полезная штука, кто пользуется, советую). Нет там такой бука-вы. Неужели в таком мощном языке нет такого знака! Тогда смотреть нужно в сторону \newcommand и \tikz. Потом покопаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Так, ну, что, нужно попробовать исправиться. Вот, что мне удалось нашаманить:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  \usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % для возможности вычислений при построении внутри окружения tikzpicture
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\vidprob}{
\raisebox{-1mm}[1pt]
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-0.2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0.2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (-0.27,0.15);
\coordinate (D) at (-0.21,0.15);
\coordinate (E) at (-0.14,0);
\coordinate (F) at ($ (D)!.52!(E) $);
\coordinate (G) at (0.27,0.15);
\coordinate (H) at (0.21,0.15);
\coordinate (I) at (0.14,0);
\coordinate (J) at ($ (H)!.52!(I) $);
\draw[fill=black] (A)--(B)--(G)--(H)--(J)--(F)--(D)--(C)--cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
Около трех с половиной \vidprob десятилетии минуло с тех пор, как в педвузах введено в качестве учебной дисциплины \vidprob программирование для ЭВМ.
За все это время педвузовские кафедры программирования \vidprob и вычислительной математики, как и образованные позднее на их основе кафедры информатики и вычислительной техники, не были избалованы своевременным появлением специальных учебных изданий.
\end{document}
```

```
<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX- 
AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'>
</script>
\newcommand{\vidprob}{
\raisebox{-1mm}[1pt]
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-0.2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0.2,0); 
\coordinate (C) at (-0.27,0.15);
\coordinate (D) at (-0.21,0.15);
\coordinate (E) at (-0.14,0);
\coordinate (F) at ($ (D)!.52!(E) $);
\coordinate (G) at (0.27,0.15);
\coordinate (H) at (0.21,0.15);
\coordinate (I) at (0.14,0);
\coordinate (J) at ($ (H)!.52!(I) $);
\draw[fill=black] (A)--(B)--(G)--(H)--(J)--(F)--(D)- 
-(C)--cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
Около трех с половиной \vidprob десятилетии минуло с 
тех пор, как в педвузах введено в качестве учебной 
дисциплины \vidprob программирование для ЭВМ.
За все это время педвузовские кафедры 
программирования \vidprob и вычислительной 
математики, как и образованные позднее на их основе 
кафедры информатики и вычислительной техники, не 
были избалованы своевременным появлением специальных 
учебных изданий.
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX- 
AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'>
</script>
\newcommand{\vidprob}{
\raisebox{-1mm}[1pt]
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-0.2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0.2,0); 
\coordinate (C) at (-0.27,0.15);
\coordinate (D) at (-0.21,0.15);
\coordinate (E) at (-0.14,0);
\coordinate (F) at ($ (D)!.52!(E) $);
\coordinate (G) at (0.27,0.15);
\coordinate (H) at (0.21,0.15);
\coordinate (I) at (0.14,0);
\coordinate (J) at ($ (H)!.52!(I) $);
\draw[fill=black] (A)--(B)--(G)--(H)--(J)--(F)--(D)- 
-(C)--cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
Около трех с половиной \vidprob десятилетии минуло с 
тех пор, как в педвузах введено в качестве учебной 
дисциплины \vidprob программирование для ЭВМ.
За все это время педвузовские кафедры 
программирования \vidprob и вычислительной 
математики, как и образованные позднее на их основе 
кафедры информатики и вычислительной техники, не 
были избалованы своевременным появлением специальных 
учебных изданий.
```

Я не знаю еще, как оттуда пакеты подключать, потому и не работает здесь этот код. А на моем компе выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изменяя координаты точек, можно подогнать форму, размеры знака под необходимые. Я просто не знаю, что нужно ТС.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
\texttt{\textvisiblespace}
```